# Why can't I copy Files or Form Data from the browser console

Tags: file, google-chrome, console, form-data

I can't copy files or form data from the chrome browser console and it's baffling to me.

I've tried

1. right click on object -> copy object
2. storing as a global variable -> use the chrome "copy(temp1)" feature
3. doing the above but stringifying it like "copy(JSON.stringify(temp1))"
4. going to the network tab and trying to copy the payload of the api call

all of these just yield an empty object "{}"

Is this a security feature? Why don't any of these work?

Comment: Just for context, what version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: @BrianBarnes Version 117.0.5938.92 (Official Build) (arm64)